# Disable all downloads in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, download

So I gave my son a laptop and so far I continuously have to factory reset after he downloads some virus and/or malware. He's obsessed with Minecraft and mods and that community seems to be a cesspool of malware.

I need a way to disable his laptop from being able to download anything, stop anything from writing to the directory, etc. Basically I would like to allow him to access the internet for school and I'll preinstall Minecraft for him before I disable the downloads. So internet and minecraft and that's it.

How do I disable all downloads and registry access?

Answer (score 2):

You could try making him a limited user, so he can't install anything to his computer, but can still run the game, access the internet, etc. You could also install a free AntiVirus, like AVG or Avast, not Norton/McAfee, that will stop most malwares.

Answer (score 1):

The best long-term solution might be to teach him *not* to download random windows programs (that often have viruses/malware). (*If* I knew the best way to do that, I'd definitely say how; I switched to Linux Mint, with tested programs from a central repository, with source code available too. This [question](https://superuser.com/questions/850766/downloading-software-without-bloatware) has some tips/programs to add programs and avoid bloatware/adware).

And/or have him go through all the trouble himself of removing the malware / factory resetting the computer? That could show him that there are some consequences to getting "infected", and he could fix it himself next time?

Some search results advise using **Windows "Parental Controls" (called "Family Safety" in Win 8)** to disable downloads, or **parental software** like "Net Nanny."

- [c|net - How to use parental controls in Windows 8](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-use-parental-controls-in-windows-8/) - *"After creating a new account with Family Safety turned on, you'll automatically be taken to the Family Safety setup section in the Control Panel"*
- [Set up Family Safety - Windows 8.1/RT8.1](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/set-up-family-safety#set-up-family-safety=windows-8)

  > Family Safety helps you set limits on your child's PC time, as well as the websites, apps, and games they can use (and when). To set up Family Safety, you'll need to sign in with an administrator account. Before you get started, make sure that each child you want to monitor has a standard user account or a child's account. Family Safety is turned on automatically if you create a child's account, but it can be turned on later on standard accounts. For more info about user accounts, see [Create a user account](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-user-account) and [User accounts: FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/user-accounts-frequently-asked-questions).

Here are a few results from searching for "disable downloads in [browser]":

- [Firefox Disable Downlaods shortcut (CTRL+J)](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1007241) - only the shortcut, so I'm not sure if it would actually stop downloads :(
  Says use the Add-on [Customizable Shortcuts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/?src=collection&collection_id=33bf10fa-666d-45a2-9bc9-491ce21671c6) Allows to customize or disable most of the shortcuts offered by Firefox
- Internet Explorer (maybe an old result though)  to ["Disable File Download in Internet Explorer"](http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/901/) says add this registry key:

  > User Key:
  >   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ Internet
  >   Settings\Zones\3]
  >   System Key:
  >   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\
  >   Internet Settings\Zones\3]
  >   Value Name: 1803 Data Type: REG_DWORD
  >   (DWORD Value)
  >   Value Data: (0 = downloads enabled, 3 = downloads
  >   disabled)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.faronics.com/products/deep-freeze/standard/
Get DeepFreeze.

You install Deepfreeze and freeze the computer with a password.  The user can still download thing and install things, but as soon as you reboot it is reset to its previous state.

You can use your password to Thaw the computer and install whatever you want and re-freeze it.

Comment: Would that let your browser bookmarks & history be updated, or would every change be lost on reboot?

Comment: @Xen2050  New bookmarks would be lost unless you used a program to sync them to a cloud.  Then when you reboot the syncing program can download the changes.  You could write the history and bookmarks to a USB drive before shutting down also.

Comment: +1 Interesting, sounds like it does a "restore" at startup, similar to using a linux overlayfs (changes only saved in ram & lost on reboot, the base files remain "read-only").

Answer (score 1):

If all he needs is a web-browser and Minecraft, I'd consider installing Ubuntu or some other Linux Distribution. Minecraft runs on Linux and if you don't give your son root access, there is less malware that can harm the system.

Another approach is to use whatever parental controls your router or ISP provide. You can probably limit what websites a specific PC can access.

The best solution of course is not to engage in technical warfare with your son but to educate him not to download stuff. I know this is much easier said than done but the tech-fix for social-problem alternative can also have serious downsides.

Comment: That is easier said but I agree it's not impossible. He's actually the only Windows user left in the house and I honestly don't know how to use Windows since I left the OS after XP. Normally I get rid of anything Windows related, even replacing all the Windows servers at work to Ubuntu as I just don't have the Windows knowledge to support them. So my fault, I know, but switching his computer to Linux is not a bad idea. The only reason he has a Windows machine to begin with is because it's cheaper to buy him an ASUS while he's 10.